# Mosaico template editing not loading consistently

Tags: mosaico

I am using CiviCRM 4.6.28 and Joomla 3.7.2 with Mosaico 1.0 enabled. I have created a new template and edited it but am finding that the editing page only loads about 50% or less of the time. When it does not load I get a red screen (the Mosaico background colour) and the template blocks do not load. There seems to be not predictable reason for this. The site is hosted by Siteground and they have checked the server for problems. has anyone else had loading problems?

Answer (score 2):

After using Mosaico from some time, I've noted that you need to make sure you've correctly installed this extension as per the [steps mentioned in the doc](https://github.com/veda-consulting/uk.co.vedaconsulting.mosaico/#ukcovedaconsultingmosaico), i.e,

1. Doc mentions you need to install [shoreditch theme](https://civicrm.org/extensions/shoreditch), [flexmailer](https://civicrm.org/extensions/flexmailer) and then Mosaico **in order**.
2. Make sure you've downloaded all the dependencies it needs to be included by executing `./bin/setup.sh -D` from your terminal.

After these steps, it worked fine for me on around 4-5 sites.